# Vertical and Horizontal navigation css

Tags: html, css

Okay so I am doing an assignment where it wants me to add css into the files using the following directions:

*Horizontal navigation lists*

- Background color = rgb(0, 0, 0)
- Text    color = rgb(255, 255, 255)
- Bold font
- Font = 10 pixels
- Kerning = 3    pixels
- vi. Hover = rgb(255, 0, 0)

  *Vertical navigation lists*
- Left    padding = 0 pixels
- No list style
- Indent the text 5 pixels
- Line height    = 3 em
- Text color = rgb(0, 0, 0)
- Hover = underline, color=rgb (255, 64, 64)

So I wrote my code but when I run it , it looks nothing like the site picture below. What did I do wrong?

```
nav.horizontal li {

background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
color: rgb(255,255,255);
font-weight: bold;
font-size:10px;

text-decoration: none;
float:left;
}

nav.horizontal li {
    letter-spacing:3px;
}
nav.horizontal li a:hover {
    color:(255,0,0)
}

nav.vertical li{

padding-left: 0px;
list-style: none;
text-indent: 5px;
line-height: 3em;
color: rgb(0,0,0)
}

 nav.vertical li:hover{
 color: rgb(255,64,64);
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

This is my HTML sheet

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>The Gresham Children's Choir</title>

  <link href="gcc_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
  <header>
     <h1><img src="proj2gcclogo.png" alt="Gresham's Children Choir" /></h1>
  </header>

  <nav class="horizontal">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News &amp; Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members Only</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support GCC</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

  <nav class="vertical">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Board</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Youth Choir</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Boy's Choir</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Girl's Choir</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mixed Choir</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Touring Choir</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>

  <section>
     <h1>About the GCC</h1>
     <p>
        Founded in 1965, the Gresham Children's Choir seeks to enhance 
        the musical development of children by instilling in them a love of
        ensemble singing. By striving for artistic excellence 
        and learning a diverse repertory of choral literature, our children
        build self-confidence and learn the joys of working together
        to create beautiful music for an appreciative audience.
     </p>

     <article>
        <h2>Artistic Director</h2>
        <img src="proj2chen.png" alt="photo" />
        <p>
           Born and raised in eastern Ohio, David Chen studied conducting, 
           voice, and piano at the University of Southern California's Thornton 
           School of Music. David returned to Gresham two years ago to take
           over direction of the GCC. The children appreciate David's demand
           for quality performances while still maintaining a fun and playful
           atmosphere.
        </p>
        <p>As a performer, he has sung in Los Angeles with the USC Thornton 
           Choral Artists under the direction of Helen Von Allen. He has
           also been working on a project to edit and perform the 
           sacred works of Hildegard of Bingen. Look for the premier
           of his efforts next summer.
        </p>
     </article>

  </section>

  <aside>
     <h2>Hear the Buzz</h2>
     <blockquote>
        <p>The Gresham Children's Choir, Boychoir, under the direction of 
          David Chen, is an outstanding cultural asset to our city. I've enjoyed
          working with them in past and look forward to future concerts
          together.<br />
          <cite>&mdash; Andrew Pauls, Director of Gresham Civic Opera</cite>
        </p>
     </blockquote>
     <blockquote>
        <p>These children are <em>artists!</em>. Don't miss them!<br />
          <cite>&mdash; Gresham Journal</cite>
        </p>
     </blockquote>
  </aside>


  <footer>
     <address>
        Gresham Children's Choir &#183;
        Mentor, OH 44061 &#183;
        (440) 555-3811
     </address>
  </footer>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that your assignement is indeed to make the page look like that picture and not hand it our ready. So go study css and learn! You'll need to use floats or better yet flexbox for the columns.

Comment: Are you trying to add scroll to the li itself? I think you're missing overflow: scroll; on the element (?)

Comment: I'm so confused as to what you are asking.

Comment: no. im just trying to format it to look like that using those instructions @KristoferGisslén